# How to properly work with RabbitMQ in NodeJS as a producer?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, node-amqp

Should I keep the connection open always or is it better to connect and disconnect only when a message is added to the queue?

If i keep the connection open at all times, the connection disconnects after about 1 hour.

[image]

I connect as follows:

```
const connection = await amqp.connect(`${this._options.url}?heartbeat=30`, { timeout: 30000, keepAlive: true  });
```

How to make the connection reconnect automatically?